# The error message "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')" occurred in the Vue Element UI checkbox component

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, element-ui

When using the el-checkbox component from Element UI, i encountered the error message "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')", and the checkbox is not being displayed.
These are my codes：

...
        
                  
                          
                          
                          
                   
        

return{
...
    ruleForm: {
                name: '',
                code: '',
                phone: '',
                sex: '',
                ethinc: '',
                date1: '',
                date2: '',
                desc: '',
                course: [],
            },
...
}

I tried to move the course array outside of ruleForm, but the validator don't work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.